# How to implement google maps api3 in an external js file?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I included a google maps script in my jsp: `src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"`

And now I'm trying to create a map using this script in another external js file

```
var mapOptions = {
      center : new google.maps.LatLng(centerLat,centerLong),
      zoom : 11,
      mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
```

When I was trying to excute it getting a js error 'google not defined'. Is there any other possibility to implement google maps api3 in an external js file?

Comment: How are you including the two files, are you sure that the second file has had time for the Google Maps API to load entirely before your script runs?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your code is trying to run before Google Maps API is fully initialized.
you better try to hold on the execution until the maps API is fully loaded.

1- Make sure that you reference Google maps script before your custom file.
2- try to hold on the execution using document.load or using jQuery's document.ready().

let me know what happened after applying the mentioned advices.